# Make unchecked checkboxes unvailable at specific amount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following sandbox with a problem that I can't solve https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-bird-cs5uj. I have an array with objects (in the example with 2 objects but in my actual project way more than 2) and the objects of the array are displayed as checkboxes. There is also a button that increases an amount and the checkboxes can only be selectable while the amount is smaller than 5. When the amount is over 5 the checkboxes that are not checked should be disabled but the ones that are checked should still be available to uncheck. Is there a way to make this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the amount is the number of available checkbox?

Comment: No it's just a counter. So for example if I'm a restaurateur and I want to make it possible to order 5 dishes and the guest picks 5 times dish A, dish B should not be selectable anymore. But dish A should still be unselectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new state `checkAbleItems`, which contains indexes of previously checked items: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-antonelli-sze7z?file=/src/App.js:76-1472).

```
export default function App() {
  const [clickedCheckbox, setClickedCheckbox] = useState([]);
  const [currentAmount, setCurrentAmount] = useState(0);
  const [checkAbleItems, setCheckAbleItems] = useState([]);

  const updateCheckbox = (checkBoxId, checkboxCheck, index) => {
    let tempClickedCheckbox = clickedCheckbox;
    tempClickedCheckbox[checkBoxId] = checkboxCheck;
    setClickedCheckbox(tempClickedCheckbox);
    setCheckAbleItems([...checkAbleItems, index]);
  };

  const increaseCurrentAmount = () => {
    let tempAmount = currentAmount;
    tempAmount++;
    setCurrentAmount(tempAmount);
    console.log(currentAmount);
  };
  console.log(checkAbleItems);
  const exampleItems = [
    {
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      name: "Doe"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {exampleItems.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={index}
              disabled={
                currentAmount > 5 && !checkAbleItems.includes(index) 
              }
              onClick={(e) => {
                updateCheckbox(e.target.id, e.target.checked, index);
              }}
            />
            {item.name}
          </label>
        );
      })}
      <div>
        <p>{currentAmount}</p>
        <button onClick={() => increaseCurrentAmount()}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```